# Android pass value Activity

Tags: android, listview

I want to pass a value from the ListView Activity 1 Activity 2 for editing.

I have this code but the value is not passed in the second Activity.

ACTIVITY A

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Modifica_entrate.class);      
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString (tv1.getText().toString(), data);
i.putExtras(extras);
```

ACTIVITY B

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String valuePass = extras.getString("data");
mDataScelta.setText(i.getExtras().getString(valuePass));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up keys and values a bit too much.

The **first** parameter here:

```
extras.putString (tv1.getText().toString(), data);
```

**Must match** the parameter here:

```
String valuePass = extras.getString("data");
```

So the code you have there puts a String with the key `tv1.getText().toString()` that is, it takes the text you entered in the textbox and uses it as a key (which is probably not what you intended to do). For this key, you are putting the *value of the variable* `data`. Then you try to retrieve the key `"data"` (note also that `data` and `"data"` are not the same thing).

So what you want is probably:

```
extras.putString("data", tv1.getText().toString());
```

And then you can retrieve it like this:

```
mDataScelta.setText(i.getStringExtra("data"));
```